# C# - Writing data in local database

Tags: c#, database, local

Im working on a program to save Passwords.

I want to write them in a local database file (Name: Database.sdf).

This is my SQL query:

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source = Database1.sdf";
conn.Open();
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Passwords (Nr, Username, Password, Email, Website, Description, Rating, DateTime) VALUES ('" + UsernameBox.Text + "', " + PasswordBox.Text + "', '" + EmailBox.Text + "', '" + WebsiteBox.Text + "', '" + DescriptionBox.Text + "'," + RatingValue.Value + "," + DateTime.Now + ")", conn);

conn.Close();
```

But somehow it doesnt work.
This is my database setup:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q348R.jpg

I want the Nr auto increment 1, ( i have setted that in the database).
I hope someone can help me out.
I've tried alot of things i found on google, but nothing seems to work.

Greetz,
Rajco

Comment: 1) Which database are you using? 2) Use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for _SQL Injection_ attacks. 3) You didn't execute your command with `ExecuteNonQuery`. 4) Don't store your passwords as a plain text.

Comment: Your query should be SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Passwords (Username, Password, Email, Website, Description, Rating, DateTime) VALUES ('" + UsernameBox.Text + "', " + PasswordBox.Text + "', '" + EmailBox.Text + "', '" + WebsiteBox.Text + "', '" + DescriptionBox.Text + "'," + RatingValue.Value + "," + DateTime.Now + ")", conn);

Comment: To add to Soner: 1. Use entity framework, 2. don't store plain text passwords!

Comment: Im using a local database (which i added in 'Add new item --> Local database). And 2, sure lets do that, and 3 how should i execute it then?

Answer (score 2):

you never executed the command.

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

before the conn.Close()

And you should look upp parameters to avoid sql-injection

http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

```
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(@"
            INSERT INTO Passwords 
                (Username, Password, Email, Website, Description, Rating, DateTime) 
            VALUES 
                (@UserName, @Password, @Email, @WebSite, @Description, @RatingValue, @DateNow)", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", UsernameBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", PasswordBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", EmailBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("WebSite", WebsiteBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Description", DescriptionBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("RatingValue", RatingValue.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddwithValue("DateNow", DateTime.Now);
```

Try to use this instead. It adds your data as parameters for the query instead.

Comment: When i have the execute query, it somehow doesnt work. Cause im using a try/catch.

Comment: There was an error pasing the query. [Token line number = 1, token like offset = 113, token in error = ,]

Comment: Check out my edited answer, set your data as parameters instead. You probably have some character missing or extra added.

Comment: I'm guessing Nr in the database is the ID for the table? You don't set that as it sets automatically.

Comment: what reference i need to add for that? cause using System.Data.SqlClient; isnt it..

Comment: Lol got it, u missed the last addwithValue without the cap W haha.

Comment: But still nothing happens in my table, if i do Show Table Data, the new line isnt in there.

Comment: I'm guessing you should use System.Data.SqlCeClient

Comment: Nope, it just seems to work fine, but nothing happens in my table.

Comment: Do you have a try/catch around this entire statement or just around the execute command?

Comment: Around the entire statement. Ehm dont actually know what you mean with that, u mean refreshed the table??